# Knight moving on a chessboard on different positions each timec

Tags: c

This code should move a knight on a chessboard 8x8 and it should show me the total moves each time. At the end it shows me 140 moves, but how is that possible if the knight can only move at most 64 times on the chessboard each time on a new position? Please answer me and let me know what I did wrong. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int board[8][8]={0};
    int currentRow=4, currentColumn=4;
    int cont=0, moveNumber, i, j, flag;

    while(moveNumber>=0 && moveNumber<=7){
        moveNumber=rand()%8;
        switch(moveNumber){
            case 0:
                currentRow--;
                currentColumn+=2;
                if(board[currentRow][currentColumn]==1 || currentRow>7 || currentColumn>7){
                    currentRow++;
                    currentColumn-=2;
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }else{
                    board[currentRow][currentColumn]=1;
                    cont++;
                    flag=1;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                currentRow-=2;
                currentColumn++;
                if(board[currentRow][currentColumn]==1 || currentRow>7 || currentColumn>7){
                    currentRow+=2;
                    currentColumn--;
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }else{
                    board[currentRow][currentColumn]=1;
                    cont++;
                    flag=1;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                currentRow-=2;
                currentColumn--;
                if(board[currentRow][currentColumn]==1 || currentRow>7 || currentColumn>7){
                    currentRow+=2;
                    currentColumn++;
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }else{
                    board[currentRow][currentColumn]=1;
                    cont++;
                    flag=1;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                currentRow--;
                currentColumn-=2;
                if(board[currentRow][currentColumn]==1 || currentRow>7 || currentColumn>7){
                    currentRow++;
                    currentColumn+=2;
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }else{
                    board[currentRow][currentColumn]=1;
                    cont++;
                    flag=1;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                currentRow++;
                currentColumn-=2;
                if(board[currentRow][currentColumn]==1 || currentRow>7 || currentColumn>7){
                    currentRow--;
                    currentColumn+=2;
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }else{
                    board[currentRow][currentColumn]=1;
                    cont++;
                    flag=1;
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                currentRow+=2;
                currentColumn--;
                if(board[currentRow][currentColumn]==1 || currentRow>7 || currentColumn>7){
                    currentRow-=2;
                    currentColumn++;
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }else{
                    board[currentRow][currentColumn]=1;
                    cont++;
                    flag=1;
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                currentRow+=2;
                currentColumn++;
                if(board[currentRow][currentColumn]==1 || currentRow>7 || currentColumn>7){
                    currentRow-=2;
                    currentColumn--;
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }else{
                    board[currentRow][currentColumn]=1;
                    cont++;
                    flag=1;
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                currentRow++;
                currentColumn+=2;
                if(board[currentRow][currentColumn]==1 || currentRow>7 || currentColumn>7){
                    currentRow--;
                    currentColumn-=2;
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }else{
                    board[currentRow][currentColumn]=1;
                    cont++;
                    flag=1;
                }
                break;
        }
        if(flag==1){
        for(i=0; i<8; i++){
            for(j=0; j<8; j++){
                printf("%d ", board[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("Total moves: %d\n",cont);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wasn't this question asked 15 minutes ago? :/

Comment: @hellow that question didn't update the position

Comment: You could improve your code a lot by doing some function (like check if a position is on the board, move the knigth, etc etc)

Comment: You have a lot of duplication in your code. You should really refactor it and use some functions.

Comment: Be carefull of what you do : you don't initialize "moveNumber" but you test it rigth away in the while ....

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing something.
in this line:

```
if(board[currentRow][currentColumn]==1 || currentRow>7 || currentColumn>7)
```

you should add

```
currentRow<0 || currentColumn<0
```

Answer (score 1):

You observe the effect of *undefined behavior*. You are using a check for an already allocated place in the board and an incomplete range change. This leads to an access out of bounds of the `board` array.

You can watch this if you dump the interesting information instead of the board. Add a line

```
printf("moveNumber: %d board[%d][%d]: %d\n", 
    moveNumber, currentRow, currentColumn, board[currentRow][currentColumn]);
```

before each assignment before of a board cell. The gives you an output like this:

```
moveNumber: 1 board[2][5]: 0
moveNumber: 3 board[1][3]: 0
moveNumber: 6 board[3][4]: 0
moveNumber: 4 board[4][2]: 0
moveNumber: 1 board[2][3]: 0
moveNumber: 4 board[3][1]: 0
moveNumber: 6 board[5][2]: 0
moveNumber: 6 board[7][3]: 0
moveNumber: 0 board[6][5]: 0
moveNumber: 1 board[4][6]: 0
moveNumber: 1 board[2][7]: 0
moveNumber: 3 board[1][5]: 0
moveNumber: 1 board[-1][6]: -858993460
moveNumber: 3 board[-2][4]: 3
```

The last two lines shows access with invalid index. This causes undefined behavior.

You can improve your program in different ways. You can extend your range change and check for negative numbers. You can also change the type of `currentRow` and `currentColumn` to unsigned, in that case your check is sufficient.

If your pseudo random generator creates a sequence that you reach all fields of the board depends on the implementation. I doubt that the usual pseudo ramdom generator allows you to fill the entire board.